Is there an Archimedean Dedekind-complete ordered division ring of characteristic zero that is non-isomorphic to the real line?
I know an Archimedean Dedekind-complete ordered field of characteristic $0$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. My question is what if I start from an ordered division ring? Would it still be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? My intuition tells me it should, since characteristic $0$ implies there is an embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$ in the ring. If this embedding is order-preserving, then $\mathbb{R}$, the Dedekind-completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, should also be embedded in the Dedekind-completion of the ring, and the embedding should respect order. Then Archimedeanness would ensure nothing lies outside of the image of $\mathbb{R}$.
But I'm not sure if the above reasoning is completely correct. Maybe a counterexample exists? Thanks in advance.
Background: I'm wondering, do we have to introduce noncommutativity in analysis, after we have arrived at functional analysis and operator theory? Is it possible to have an analysis with noncommutativity built-in from the ground up? That is, not of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ but a noncommutative division ring? But if the answer to my question is no, then this attempt would be in veil. So just wondering.

Archimedean ordered division rings are necessarily commutative.  A proof can be found in Hilbert's Foundations of Geometry:
https://archive.org/details/thefoundationsof17384gut/page/n69/mode/2up

Maybe you want to start with

Neumann, Bernhard H. "On ordered division rings." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 66.1 (1949): 202-252.

Part II is: "embedding the real numbers in an ordered division ring."  The author says

It is well known that every ordered field can be embedded
in an ordered field enjoying certain completeness or continuity properties ; in particular every ordered field can be so extended as to contain (a subfield order-isomorphic to) the field of all real numbers. The main result we prove here is that this remains true for ordered division rings. The methods required to establish this are, however, much more elaborate than in the commutative case.

On a superficial reading I cannot really say they consider the Archimedean condition in the second part, but the author is certainly using it in the first part.

Thanks a lot! I'll start reading it. I'll also wait and see if there are more definitive answers posted in a few days.
